# Config Babel-preset-stage-0 in Webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I try to add babel-preset-stage 0 in my webpack.config.js
Here is the code for my configuration:

```js
module.exports = {
  entry: './app/app.jsx',
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: './public/bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    root: __dirname,
    alias: {
    },
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['stage-0', 'react', 'es2015']
        },
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

However, I end up with this error:

```js
ERROR in ./app/app.jsx
Module build failed: TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined
    at assertPath (path.js:28:11)
    at Object.dirname (path.js:1345:5)
    at /Users/annguyen/Documents/React/ReactWeather/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:374:36
    at /Users/annguyen/Documents/React/ReactWeather/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:396:22
    at Array.map (native)
    at OptionManager.resolvePresets (/Users/annguyen/Documents/React/ReactWeather/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:385:20)
    at OptionManager.mergePresets (/Users/annguyen/Documents/React/ReactWeather/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:369:10)
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (/Users/annguyen/Documents/React/ReactWeather/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:328:14)
    at /Users/annguyen/Documents/React/ReactWeather/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:370:14
    at /Users/annguyen/Documents/React/ReactWeather/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:390:24
    at Array.map (native)
    at OptionManager.resolvePresets (/Users/annguyen/Documents/React/ReactWeather/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:385:20)
    at OptionManager.mergePresets (/Users/annguyen/Documents/React/ReactWeather/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:369:10)
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (/Users/annguyen/Documents/React/ReactWeather/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:328:14)
    at OptionManager.init (/Users/annguyen/Documents/React/ReactWeather/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:481:10)
    at File.initOptions (/Users/annguyen/Documents/React/ReactWeather/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:211:75)
    at new File (/Users/annguyen/Documents/React/ReactWeather/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:129:22)
    at Pipeline.transform (/Users/annguyen/Documents/React/ReactWeather/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/pipeline.js:48:16)
    at transpile (/Users/annguyen/Documents/React/ReactWeather/node_modules/babel-loader/index.js:14:22)
    at Object.module.exports (/Users/annguyen/Documents/React/ReactWeather/node_modules/babel-loader/index.js:88:12)
```

When I remove the 'stage-0' in presets, it works perfectly fine.
Here is my dev dependencies:

```js
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.5.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^1.12.13"
  }
```

Comment: show the whole webpack config file and package.json file (with imports/requires() )

Comment: did you find a resolution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's recomended to add `.babelrc`in the root of your project and then:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "stage-0",
    "react"
  ]
}
```